# Laravel One Model Multiple Controllers

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table named '**contacts**' and it has the '**is_company**' field. This field gets value 0 and 1.
And I have two controller named **ContactController** and **CompanyController**. I'm saving data to table from  ContactController -> is_company = 0, from CompanyController -> is_company = 1.

I cannot use a single controller. Because views and other information which stored in the table are different.

Here is my route

```
  Route::resource('contacts','ContactController')->middleware('auth');
  Route::resource('companies','CompanyController')->middleware('auth');
```

And here is controller

```
 public function show(Contact $contact)
{

    $act = Activity::all();
    $reg = Region::all();
    $type = UserType::all();
    $provinces = DB::table('regions')->where('parent', '=',0)->get();
    $regions = DB::table('regions')->where('parent', '!=',0)->get();       
    return view('contacts.show', compact('contact','act','reg','type', 'provinces', 'regions'));
}
```

This function is the same at both controllers.

Here is a view of companies.index

```
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{route('companies.show',$contact->id)}}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></a>
```

Here is a view of companies.show

```
 <form role="form" action="{{route('companies.update', $contact->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div class="card-body">
      ******
```

This method works normally when I doing something with the Contacts route. But I'm getting errors at CompanyController because there is no model with a named Company. How can I solve this? Any suggestions?

How can I use a single Model for two Controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel `::resource()` routes automatically generate a set of routes based on a particular scheme. This scheme assumes that a model of the corresponding name exists.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

For example, the following `show` URL is presumed. You can see it is looking for a variable named `company`, not `contact`.

```php
Route::get('companies/{company}','CompanyController@show');
```

You have a few options that come to mind:

1. Manually define the routes for the CompanyController using `contact` as the input.

For example:

```php
Route::get('companies/{contact}','CompanyController@show');
```

2. Change the name of the variable in your CompanyController from `$contact` to `$company`.

```php
public function show(Contact $company)
{
    // ...
}
```

3. Create a Company model.

You could even extend the Contact model to pass through existing methods, if desired. Then you would reference the Company model in your controller instead of Contact. You could even set up a global scope to only return Companies when referencing this model, which may make this option very useful.

```php
class Company extends Contact
{
   protected $table = 'contacts';

   // ...
}
```